# How to Create a Simple If Condition Syntax in Crystal Report Formula that Returns a String Value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, functional-programming

Can Anyone help learn about Crystal Reports Formula Syntax i have currently made a code but it keeps saying Error 'there was an error in this formula'.

i have this already:

```
If {Dataset.Gender} = "MALE" Then  
// Return String X  
End If
```

i have tried researching for the right one syntax and seems like i already have written the right one but still not working why is it?

can anyone fix my syntax on how to return an X value if it's a male in crystal reports formula.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "End if" From the formula

If {Dataset.Gender} = "MALE" Then
// Return String X

Comment: it still saying error i don't what's making it error.. return string how can i change the value like on the report it would show an X or hello value?

Comment: Check the datatype for gender it String or bit or int that might me the issue. otherwise the formula is correct.

Comment: it's Nvarchar(100) which is why i put a condition of string either "MALE" or "FEMALE"

Comment: using any  subreports

Comment: no sir. just want to create an answer for a checkbox. like if it's a male then on this formula string will be x to occupied a checkbox. and if it's a female i should be creating another formula string for another output display x and the male formula wouldn't show an x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101274/discussion-between-mahendra-and-detective7).